# unit testing spring boot with mockito

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

So i have searched all related questions here and found no answer that worked on mine. With that being said I am trying to unit test my spring-boot application with Mockito.

Here is my controller and the function i am trying to test.

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

   @Autowired
   UserRepository userRepository;


   @GetMapping("/user")
   public List<User> getAllUsers() {
       return userRepository.findAll();
   }

   @GetMapping("/user/{id}")
   public User getUser(@PathVariable Integer id) {
       return userRepository.findById(id).get();
   }
```

I am trying to test `getUser` function

here is my Test Controller

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

public class UserControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private UserController userController;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(userController).build();
    }
    @Test
    public void getUserTest() throws Exception{

  mockMvc.perform(get("/user/100").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith("application/json"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.role").value("deliverer"));

    }
```

So firstly when I run this i get following error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Content type not set

    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:37)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertTrue(AssertionErrors.java:70)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertNotNull(AssertionErrors.java:106)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.ContentResultMatchers.lambda$contentTypeCompatibleWith$1(ContentResultMatchers.java:103)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:196)
    at eldercare.RESTapi.controller.UserControllerTest.getUserTest(UserControllerTest.java:57)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

with following data being printed

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = []
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

I have tested putting `@ResponseBody` in my Controller does not make any difference. I have also tested as stated in other post `@RequestMapping(value="/user/{id}", method= RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)` that doesn't work either still get the same error.

If I dont have this check `.andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith("application/json"))` then i get the error stating `java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.role"`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be mocking the UserRepository and not the UserController.

Comment: No , mocking repository gives me status error because there is no such url there ..... I have to mock Controller for it to work , its just it keep on complaining on Content type not set...

Comment: If you mock the controller you are testing the mock, not your implementation. You need to autowire the controller, so that you get the bean created by your setup, rather than a mock.